# How to add a comma between author and year

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I use the `authoryear` style in `biblatex`, and when I do for instance `\cite{bauman2000}`, I get:

> Bauman 2000

But I would like to add a comma between the author and the year, in order to have

> Bauman, 2000

Is there a simple command to get this change ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Welcome to this site. I hope you will have a wonderful time here.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The space between the name and the year is controlled by the macro `\nameyeardelim`. So you have to redefine it:

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Here a small example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\begin{document}
\cite{companion}
\end{document}
```

The default definition can be found in the file `biblatex.def`. There are other useful definitions are also done.

Comment: Thanks it works !! Is there a way to flag this question as "resolved" ?

Comment: @Leo: Yes, there is a checkmark under the arrows. I am glad that it helps.

Comment: The number of small changes I've had to add to biblatex in order to make it produce standard citations is amazing.. Makes me wonder if this is the best option anyway.

Comment: After adding the above line in my code, I got "... command already defined ..." error. I then edited corresponding line in the default definition file biblatex.def (in my system it is located in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def). Then it worked. Editing this file may require permission.

Comment: In more recent versions of `biblatex` `nameyeardelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter, so `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` would be the preferred way to do the same thing as in this answer.

Comment: I altered the file suggested by @Sisay Chala and it did not work for me.

Comment: But `\newcommand{\citeay}{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}}` in the preamble did the trick. This was suggested here:https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7819

Comment: `citealp{citation}` also works. See https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf