# Adding comma after TITLE (before year) in citation

Tags: biblatex, citing

This question can be seen as an extension to this one ([How to add a comma between author and year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134063/how-to-add-a-comma-between-author-and-year)) which does not, however, contain an answer to my question.

In the same context, I am trying to modify the citation style so that there is a comma separating the author and the year, as in:

> (Author, 2016)

. I managed to achieve that by modifying biblatex.def file with following.

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

My problem now is that I cannot seem to find  `\titleyeardelim` or some "default" (if such exists) delimiter which is used in cases where the author is absent and the title is used instead. Consequentially I'm getting

> (Title 2016)

in all my citations instead of the required:

> (Title, 2016)

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Is `\nonameyeardelim` the chap you are looking for? (This is a new command in `biblatex` 3.3.)

Comment: Thanks @moewe , it really sounds like something I'm looking for, especially after I have checked, I am still running v0.99d! However the trick is that I have already made a number of modification to various config files (over a period of 6 month) to suit my needs for referencing and it would be too great of a risk to take to update Bibtex and hope that I will be able to do such modifications again (or at least in time for the deadline). Therefore I'm stuck with the current version and have to make the best of it.

Comment: v0.99d is the BibTeX version, I believe, not the `biblatex` version. Which style are you using `authoryear`?

Comment: @moewe Yes it is indeed,  Biblatex version: 3.0, my apologies. I am using `style=authoryear`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from version 3.3 of `biblatex`, there is the command `\nonameyeardelim` that you can redefine

```
\renewcommand*{\nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

---

If you run an older version of `biblatex` you will need to modify the cite macro itself, with the `authoryear` style that is

```
\providecommand*{\nonameyeardelim}{\nameyeardelim}
\renewcommand*{\nonameyeardelim}{\nameyeardelim}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\nonameyeardelim}}%% <-- this line needed to be changed
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

Comment: Thank you @moewe, for the detailed answer. It did help me a lot and at the end I managed to get the citations just the way I need them. Although I got the desired results by modifying a different line than in the answer provided. For the sake others who might read this and are (like me) not very confident in this the file I have modified is the style file (`authoryear.cbx`). And the modification I made are as follows:
`\setunit{\addcomma\space}}`  original line `setunit{\addspace}}`, form the answer above.

Comment: @Konaras Please note that you should not modify the global package files directly. Those modifications are undone if you update the packages. With `biblatex` it is very easy to roll your own style based on an existing one or to just stuff all the code in the preamble. See for example [Biblatex.cfg vs .cls vs .sty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296732/35864). I don' quite understand how your solution differs from what I have done except that I have used `\nonameyeardelim` and let it default to `\nameyeardelim` which with your setup should be `\addcoma\space`.