# How to add a comma between author and year in biblatex-philosophy?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

I'm new to LaTeX (and Stack Exchange - apologies in advance for any inadvertent misdemeanours), and am grappling with changing `biblatex-philosophy` styles.

My question is, how can I add a comma after the author and before the year?

The answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300686/adding-comma-after-title-before-year-in-citation) does not seem to work with `biblatex-philosophy`. I'm getting a vague idea as to how to make style changes to `biblatex`, but the added complexity of changes to an addon is beyond me at the moment.

Here's the format I need:
[image: Target]
*Note the comma even after the author's initial.

I'm most of the way there with the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Bibliography preamble
\usepackage[giveninits=true, style=philosophy-modern]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

% Some tweaks I've already made
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} % Remove quotations from Article title
\setlength{\yeartitle}{5.4em} % Set greater spacing between the year and the title
\setlength{\postnamesep}{2.5ex plus 2pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}
Sentence containing citation \parencite{pavese1965}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and `.bib` file:

```
@book{pavese1965,
    Author = {Pavese, Cesare},
    Publisher = {University of Michigan Press},
    Title = {Dialogues with Leucò},
    date = {1965},
    Editor = {William Arrowsmith and D. S. Carne-Ross},
    editortype = {translator},
    Location = {Ann Arbor}}
```

Which outputs:

[image: Attempt]

As you can see, there's just a couple of slight changes to be made (I'll ask a separate question about how to change "trans. by" to just "trans.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We only need to add `\addcomma` to the original definition of `\postsep`

```
\renewcommand{\postsep}{%
  \addcomma
  \null\par\nobreak\vskip\postnamesep%
    \hskip-\bibhang\ignorespaces}
```

In total

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Bibliography preamble
\usepackage[giveninits=true, style=philosophy-modern]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Some tweaks I've already made
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} % Remove quotations from Article title
\setlength{\yeartitle}{5.4em} % Set greater spacing between the year and the title
\setlength{\postnamesep}{2.5ex plus 2pt minus 1pt}

\renewcommand{\postsep}{%
  \addcomma
  \null\par\nobreak\vskip\postnamesep%
    \hskip-\bibhang\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
Sentence containing citation \parencite{sigfridsson,vizedom:related,worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

we get

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quick and easy edit. I'll now track down the definitions of each compenent of \postsep. Everywhere I turn at the moment there's five new commands I've never seen before!