# Insert comma between author and year for authoryear citations

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` and I am trying to put a comma between the author and year.

If I use

```
\parencite{GrandViewResearch2019}
```

the result is

> (Grand View Research 2019)

instead of

> (Grand View Research, 2019)

I have tried the different solutions proposed in this post, but unsuccessfully it didn't work. Maybe the command has been changed since 2013?

[How to add a comma between author and year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134063/how-to-add-a-comma-between-author-and-year)

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

should still work, but `nameyeardelim` is a context-senstive delimiter now, so you should use

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

with a current version of `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998)]

Comment: @Kalandrak Do not use both! Just use one of the two: `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` with a current version of `biblatex` and  `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` for outdated versions of `biblatex`.

Comment: @Kalandrak I really can't imagine a legitimate situation where both commands might be needed. So if you have one, I'd be very eager to see it. Can you prepare a short example document/MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: Thank you moewe. I did the change as you suggested, and it is working fine (current version of biblatex).