# Missing comma between author and year in the reference of the maintext

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm new to LaTeX and am using the `Harvard-style` template on `overleaf`. 
Following is my file:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,scale=0.8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\let\cite\parencite

\addbibresource{Ref.bib}% Syntax for version >= 1.2

\title{}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My problem is when I use `\cite{{pauling1960, repp2004}}`, I got `(Pauling 1960; Repp et al. 2004)` rather than `(Pauling, 1960; Repp et al., 2004)`. The comma is missing.

What's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a comma between author and year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134063/how-to-add-a-comma-between-author-and-year)

Comment: Yes, it's solved. Many thanks!

Comment: I recommend **not** to say `\let\cite\parencite`. Use `\autocite` instead, then you can easily switch between citation styles on the fly (via the option `autocite`).

Comment: @moewe Thank you! I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of:

[How to add a comma between author and year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134063/how-to-add-a-comma-between-author-and-year)

and

[Insert comma between author and year for authoryear citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543330/insert-comma-between-author-and-year-for-authoryear-citations)

Anyway, the answer is, for older versions of biblatex use:

`\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`

and for recent versions use:

`\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`

Do **not** use both. They should be inserted in your preamble.

Comment: Thank you so much~~